# How to remove last character from URL? (/uxjkau/234213c to /uxjkau/234213)

Tags: nginx, redirect, url-rewriting

I am not sure how to get nginx to do this. For the following URLs:

```
example.com/something/uxjkau/234213c
example.com/different/ixcudj/178427129p
example.com/totally/nmvkewdsdfw/45892347632c
```

They should redirect to:

```
example.com/something/uxjkau/234213
example.com/different/ixcudj/178427129
example.com/totally/nmvkewdsdfw/45892347632
```

So basically just stripping the last character of the URL. But there are already valid URLs that don't need to have their last character stripped (example.com/bananas/7346274).

Last character only needs to be stripped if it's a letter, not number. Also most likely the character will be either c or p (lowercase).

Tried some redirects in nginx with regex but really bad at regex so no luck.

Comment: Something like `rewrite ^(.*/[0-9]+)[cp]$ $1 permanent;`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
rewrite ^((?:(?![a-zA-Z]$).)*)[a-zA-Z]?$ $1;
```